# mysql php query same table 5 times using the same alias but use that alias for a different column each time

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have a table that stores 5 different grid coordinates that i need to list out by the shortest distance from a given coordinate. So i thought i would use union and query the table 5 times each time use the alias for a different column. but it seems each the alias returns the value of the first select. here is the query i have tried.

```
SELECT floor(sqrt(pow((cord_1x-$cord1x),2)+pow((cord_1y-$cord1y),2))) as distance,
  alliance_name, player_name, level, priority,cord_1x AS cordx, cord_1y AS cordy, 
  cord_2x, cord_2y, cord_3x, cord_3y, cord_4x, cord_4y, cord_5x, cord_5y 
FROM cords 
where alliance_id = " .$myalliance_id. " AND cord_1x <> '' AND active ='1'
UNION 
SELECT floor(sqrt(pow((cord_2x-$cord1x),2)+pow((cord_2y-$cord1y),2))) as distance, 
  alliance_name, player_name, level, priority,cord_1x, cord_1y, 
  cord_2x AS cordx, cord_2y AS cordy, cord_3x, cord_3y, cord_4x, cord_4y, cord_5x, cord_5y 
FROM cords 
where alliance_id = " .$myalliance_id. " AND cord_2x <> ''  and active ='1' 
order by distance ASC";
```

the result i am trying to get is

player_name  alliance_name  level  priority distance  cord
     jon         bad guys      10      high     4        1,1
     jon         bad guys      10      high     6        2,2

what i am getting is

player_name  alliance_name  level  priority distance  cord
     jon         bad guys      10      high     4        1,1
     jon         bad guys      10      high     6        1,1

it looks like my use of alias is not right. it wont apply the value for the next column to the same alias name use in the first select.

keep in mind i only used 2 selects for testing purposes its easier but when i figure this out i will query the table 5 times

Comment: the problem i am having is i need cord_1x as cordx for first select but i need cord_2x as cordx on second select. but the second select seems to return cordx with the value it was given in the first select. the distance alias is working properly though

Answer (score 0):

First, use `UNION ALL`. You don't want `UNION` deciding to merge two resultset rows because they're the same.

Second, for the two subqueries in your `UNION ALL` operation, you should conform the columns by name, datatype, and position.  You're trying to conform them only by name and datatype.

That is, you need something like this:

```
SELECT floor(sqrt(pow((cord_1x-$cord1x),2)+pow((cord_1y-$cord1y),2))) as distance,
       alliance_name, player_name, level, priority,
       cord_1x AS cordx, cord_1y AS cordy,  /*alias columns */
       cord_1x, cord_1y, cord_2x, cord_2y,  /* cord_1 columns repeat */
       cord_3x, cord_3y, cord_4x, cord_4y, cord_5x, cord_5y 
  FROM cords 
 where alliance_id = " .$myalliance_id. " AND cord_1x <> '' AND active ='1'
UNION ALL
SELECT floor(sqrt(pow((cord_2x-$cord1x),2)+pow((cord_2y-$cord1y),2))) as distance, 
       alliance_name, player_name, level, priority,
       cord_2x AS cordx, cord_2y AS cordy,    /* different alias columns */
       cord_1x, cord_1y, cord_2x, cord_2y,    /* cord_2 columns repeat */
       cord_3x, cord_3y, cord_4x, cord_4y, cord_5x, cord_5y 
  FROM cords 
  where alliance_id = " .$myalliance_id. " AND cord_2x <> ''  and active ='1' 
  order by distance ASC";
```